# Give two divs the same height

Tags: html, css

I have two div's in one wrapper div, see the following situation:

```
<div class="container">
 <div style="display:table;" class="row row-mobile fp-white-row">

  <div style="display:table-cell;" class="col-sm-6 portfolio-post-l">
    <h1><?php the_field('port_kop_linker_kolom'); ?></h1>
    <?php the_field('port_inhoud_linker_kolom'); ?>
  </div>

  <div style="display:table-cell;" class="col-sm-6 portfolio-post-r">
    <h1><?php the_field('port_kop_rechter_kolom'); ?></h1>
    <?php the_field('port_inhoud_rechter_kolom'); ?>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

I would like `portfolio-post-l` to be the same height as `portfolio-post-r` and the other way around if necessary. How can I accomplish this? it is needed because the `portfolio-post-l` has an border and should stretch to the bottom of the wrapper div `row row-mobile fp-white-row`.
I know a solution is to give the `portfolio-post-r` a left border, but what if the right border becomes the shortest div? I need to ensure it works both ways no matter who's the taller div.

[Here an image of my current layout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydra6d5u0k7mfny/Screenshot%202014-09-29%2009.20.15.png?dl=0)

I have searched online for about an hour and couldn't find any simple solution, all had to do with JS or `display:table` that did not work for me.
Is it really that inconvenient to include this functionality?

thanks!

**EDIT 01**
I have no CSS applied to my `.portfolio-post-l` & `.portfolio-post-r` other then a background color and a border. However, Bootstrap applies CSS to the `col-sm-6`, here's that CSS:

```
width: 50%;
float: left;
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
```

I just found out, thanks to **Krzysiek** that `col-sm-6` is messing up the `table` display fix. If I remove that class, it works, however, I would like to keep it because it's a Bootstrap class used for laying out the page....
[Here's a Fiddle of my layout](http://jsfiddle.net/boriskamp1991/w3xpn19k/2)
I think it has to do with positioning, anybody any suggestions?

Thanks!

**/Edit 01**

Comment: you can give min-height for portfolio-post-l & portfolio-post-r

Comment: Your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/6dcazw8q/ . The two blocks have the same height

Comment: Did you tried to remove `col-sm-6` class and add `width:50%;`? Can you paste css code for `portfolio-post-l/r`?

Comment: Giving `min-height` is not a dynamic solution. It's working in your fiddle Anon, thats wierd! It's not working on my end....  Krzysiek, see my updated first post for more info. Thanks!

Comment: @BorisKamp Make a fiddle or something. Using table and table cell should work.

Comment: @BorisKamp Ruddy is right. You have used display:table & display: table-cell. They should work, as you can see in Anon's fiddle. May I ask which browser & browser version are you using?

Comment: The problem is not browser related, I think the issue is caused by Bootstrap's `col` classes I added (and need) like I said in my first post. How can we work around this? Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boriskamp1991/w3xpn19k/2/ Please make sure to resize the `result` window so you can see the 1 and 2 column layout. If you remove the `col` classes, it does work but breaks the layout.